# How to insert result from a cursor into a tempTable

Tags: sql-server, cursor, temp-tables

I have around 60 databases that I am querying against that have the same tables; however, I want the result of my query to be inserted into a temp table so that I can create a well formatted report using the result stored in that temp table.
How do I achieve that?
Below is my query that loops through each database and run the query to select all active orders:

```
DECLARE @db_name Varchar(100)

DECLARE @SQL Varchar(3000)

DECLARE c_db_names CURSOR FOR
SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE name NOT IN('master','AdventureWorks2008','TestDB','Development','Northwind') --might need to exclude more databases

OPEN c_db_names

FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN   

SET @SQL = 'SELECT OrderID, OrderStatus, OrderDetails, FulfillmentDate, ShippingDate , AddDate from 
       '+ @db_name +'.dbo.ActiveOrders inner join '+ @db_name +'.dbo.FinalShipmentNumbers on '+ @db_name +'.dbo.ActiveOrders.OrderDetails = 
       '+ @db_name +'.dbo.FinalShipmentNumbers.OrderID where addDate between ''1/30/2016'' and ''2/26/2016'''

SELECT @db_name As Client_Name
EXEC(@SQL)      
FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name
END

CLOSE c_db_names
DEALLOCATE c_db_names
```

Comment: With an insert statement perhaps?

Comment: where to add it in the above query I provided? I read the SELECT * INTO tempTable should work, but how to do it with this one?

Comment: Select INTO only works when the target table does not exist. Obviously in a cursor it will exist on the second time through so it would fail. I think you are way overthinking this and making more complicated than it need to be. Create a temp table and add the insert into #YourTable right before the select statement as part of your dynamic sql. The context of your dynamic sql will always be the database you start from.

Comment: There are two SELECT statements that are running within this query, the first is returning the Client name so that I know the result belongs to which database, and the second, the EXEC(@SQL) loops through the tables of each database. How to insert both?

Comment: Right....as I said. Put the insert inside your dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic syntax of how this would be.

```
SET @SQL = 'INSERT #YourTempTableHere (ColumnList)
SELECT OrderID, OrderStatus, OrderDetails, FulfillmentDate, ShippingDate , AddDate from 
       '+ @db_name +'.dbo.ActiveOrders inner join '+ @db_name +'.dbo.FinalShipmentNumbers on '+ @db_name +'.dbo.ActiveOrders.OrderDetails = 
       '+ @db_name +'.dbo.FinalShipmentNumbers.OrderID where addDate between ''1/30/2016'' and ''2/26/2016'''
```

Comment: @Jesus - thanks for the edit but INTO is actually an optional keyword. As such it is neither more correct nor incorrect to include it or exclude it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Comment: My apologies. I was firmly convinced it was required.

Comment: @JesúsLópez no need to apologize at all. Just clarifying it is not required. :)